# Java Conversion from Seconds to other measurements fail at some increments

Tags: processing, long-integer, brute-force

I'm doing a project where I calculate the time it takes to brute force a certain password in Processing (Java based). I have it working, except when the number gets insanely high, it bugs out and goes down. I figured this was due to limits of integers, so I changed to it long instead, and it still happened.
The weird thing is, it works if I make the number even higher, as show in this GIF:
https://gyazo.com/7c50600acc5b0f03ff3634d49f85c9ef

Here's the code that calculates it:

```
int pwLength = password.length();
totalChars = upperChar + lowerChar + intChar + specialChar;
float combinations = pow(totalChars, pwLength);
String bruteForceFinal = "";
float keysPerSec = 15050850.21;
float bruteForceTime  = combinations/keysPerSec;

if(bruteForceTime >= 1)
{
  long seconds = floor((bruteForceTime) % 60);
  long minutes = floor((bruteForceTime / (60)) % 60);
  long hours = floor((bruteForceTime / (60 * 60)) % 24);
  long days = floor((bruteForceTime / (60 * 60 * 24)) % 30);
  long months = floor((bruteForceTime / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)) % 12);
  long years = floor((bruteForceTime / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12)));

if((years == 0) && (months != 0))
  {
    bruteForceFinal = (months + " Months " + days + " Days " + hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ");
  } else if((months == 0) && (days != 0))
  {
    bruteForceFinal = (days + " Days " + hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ");
  } else if((days == 0) && (hours != 0))
  {
    bruteForceFinal = (hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ");
  } else if((hours == 0) && (minutes != 0))
  {
    bruteForceFinal = (minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ");
  } else if((minutes == 0) && (seconds != 0))
  {
    bruteForceFinal = (seconds + " Seconds ");
  } else 
  {
    bruteForceFinal = (years + " Years " + months + " Months " + days + " Days " + hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ");
  }
} else if((bruteForceTime < 1) && (bruteForceTime > 0.001))
{
  bruteForceFinal = (round(bruteForceTime * 1000) + " Milliseconds");
}
else
{
  bruteForceFinal = "Less than a millisecond";
}
```

I've tried some different solutions but it seems very weird that it doesn't work with one increment, but the next one works.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What values does it fail on, exactly?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Seems like you're close.

Comment: @markspace you can see in the gif if i add another t to the password it outputs a completely wrong time. And then when i add one more it shows the right time again

Comment: Actually I can't tell what's going on in that animated gif at all.  Sorry but that's the worst way of showing computer output yet.  I'm adding a second vote for a [MCVE], not a GIF.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m5TyyvNV
Here's the full code, so you can see everything, the code mentioned is all the way at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience about the GIF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, I believe, in your conditional logic.  You're assuming that if, for example, **month == 0**, then you're talking about a quantity shorter than a month.  But the total time can involve years, and yet month can happen to come out as **0**.  I think that's why you're seeing the apparent randomness.

I reproduced your results as best I could, and saw the bad behavior.  Then I took out all the conditionals to always print all the quantities, and I got:

```
0 Years 0 Months 0 Days 0 Hours 4 Minutes 6 Seconds 
0 Years 0 Months 0 Days 5 Hours 36 Minutes 38 Seconds 
4 Years 4 Months 11 Days 22 Hours 34 Minutes 8 Seconds 
358 Years 0 Months 19 Days 2 Hours 24 Minutes 28 Seconds 
29360 Years 4 Months 7 Days 8 Hours 56 Minutes 44 Seconds 
2407548 Years 10 Months 18 Days 16 Hours 28 Minutes 28 Seconds 
197419008 Years 0 Months 0 Days 0 Hours 24 Minutes 12 Seconds 
16188359680 Years 0 Months 2 Days 0 Hours 16 Minutes 20 Seconds
```

I think that all the zero quantities in the results were leading to your code using the wrong print calls.  I can't know for sure because I didn't have your exact character counts.

In short, you need to check for all the larger quantities to be zero and not assume that if some quantities are 0, bigger ones must be too.